# Why was lord Muu's fissioned clone not affected by the Earth Release: Ultra-Added-Weight Rock Technique?

Tags: naruto

During the 4th shinobi war, during Onoki vs Muu fight. Onoki makes Muu's body so heavy that he can't even lift his hands using the [Earth Release: Ultra-Added-Weight Rock Technique](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Earth_Release:_Ultra-Added-Weight_Rock_Technique).

After this Lord Muu using his [Fission jutsu](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Fission_Technique) to become as two people with halved power.

My doubt is why is the fissioned clone not affected by the Earth Release: Ultra-Added-Weight Rock Technique? The single person becomes two when the fission Jutsu is used and also their power is equally shared. Then is equal part must hold true for the Damage taken also right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mū **splitted first** (using the Fission Technique) before Ōnoki made him (his fission clone) heavier.

This was the order:

1. Naruto attacked Mū using Planetary Rasengan
2. Mū splitted his body **while being hit** by Naruto's Planetary Rasengan
3. Somehow no one noticed this
4. Ōnoki came to his fission clone and made him heavier

Comment: `Somehow no one noticed this` It's the art of misdirection! :)

Comment: I clearly remember that onoki stops Mu who's falling from the Naruto's attack and applying the heavy jutsu.

Comment: @Bej Yes. That Mū was the fission clone. Or I don't think we can call it a clone since the Fission Technique literally splits you equally. So there were 2 literal Mū, each with half power, and then Ōnoki heavied one of them.

Comment: @Bej please accept the answer if you're satisfied.